# When adding a new member to Mongodb replicaset, do I need to update the connection URI

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

- When adding a new member to MongoDB replica set, do I need to update the connection URI?
- What about the new member is going to be primary?

If service can not be restarted and old URI still in use, what will happen after adding a member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to add the new member to the list in the connection string if you add a new member. The drivers will automatically find out about the new member, and will route queries against it when required (if it becomes the primary for example).

Having said that, you should have the *majority* of your data carrying nodes in your connection string. If you have a majority of your nodes in your connection string, you can guarantee that the driver can always connect and find the primary. If has fewer nodes, then it is possible that if these nodes are part of a non-majority partition, you can not find a replicaset primary among them (because the *majority* partition will have this primary node).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a follow-up question. Connecting only through arbiter seems not working, is this a rule or a configuration?

Comment: @Vimos you should post that as a separate question, because it needs a lot of contextual information before anybody can answer.